# Upload custom YouTube thumbnail?

Tags: youtube

Is it no longer possible to upload a custom thumbnail for your YouTube videos using the new YouTube "info and settings" panel in the video manager? I read articles saying click the "Upload thumbnail" button, but I see no such button (see screenshot):

[image: Youtube Video Settings]

Comment: no, you cannot ASAIK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regular user accounts are unable to upload custom thumbnails for their videos, however, Youtube partners are able to upload their own custom thumbnails.

However, doing a little searching apparently there's a grey-hat way to do this for non-partner, but there's a pretty big risk in using this method since Youtube could ban your account: [Custom Thumbnail for Non-Partners](http://www.reelseo.com/custom-youtube-thumbnail-images-for-non-partners/)

Answer (score 0):

edit your videos.

when i want to have my desire thumbnail. go to that frame that YouTube select it from half of my video. and edit it.

replace  5 second before and after (of above frame that YouTube select) that video , with your desired frame. with softwares like : adobe captivate , adobe premier , Camtasia studio

this frame found about  50 % of your video that you can select it with progress bar about half of your video.